# OSGeo4W Shell font issue

Tags: osgeo4w, font

I'm trying to run OSGeo4W shell and the only font available is *ＭＳ ゴシック.  It's a real pain since it uses a weird "Y" instead of "\" making it hard to read commands.  Does anybody know how to activate consolas or another font?  I'm having the same problem on other command prompt programs as well.

In the registry editor I shows I have Lucida Console and Consolas as options but they don't show up in the shell.

Comment: If  this is a general problem with shell/command window programs, it's not specific to GIS. I would search on [superuser](http://superuser.com). What about this [Q&A](http://superuser.com/questions/104030/what-font-does-cmd-exe-use-by-default-for-output-in-windows-xp)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.  Runing the command "chcp 437" changes it to english.  Then I can select and english font.  Apparently it was in japanese.